# How can I extend an object after multiple requests in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I need to retrieve data from different sources, merge them all and then output all data.

I know angular supports angular.extend() for this purpose, but I cannot make it work. I only can output the result of the last http request...

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/7nq038nExDguK48cTI0w?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,$http) { 

$scope.user = {};
$http.get('data3.json').success(function(result){
   console.log(result)
   angular.extend($scope.user, result)
})

$http.get('data2.json').success(function(result){
   console.log(result)
   angular.extend($scope.user, result)
})

$http.get('data.json').success(function(result){
   console.log(result)
   angular.extend($scope.user, result)
})

});
```

Comment: Your module is called "*plunker*" do you actually have a plunker with your code?

Comment: You can't "extend" an object with an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't extend the `user` object with an array. I updated your plunker and changed the json files to make it work.

http://plnkr.co/edit/fU4BXYG9aO9O7NFDDLIb